# Show Button When Box is Checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am building a subscription preference center and I want show a button on the page, if a subscription is checked (meaning they have opted in to receiving those types of emails).

- When a subscription is not checked it shows this:

`<input id="id_10139347" type="checkbox" name="id_10139347" >`

- When a subscription is checked it shows this:

`<input id="id_10139347" type="checkbox" name="id_10139347" checked>`

How can I utilize the phrase "checked" in the second bullet point so that it shows a button on the webpage?

Comment: It depends where in the DOM tree the button is located. If it's a sibling, it can be done using CSS and the `:checked ~` selector. If not, you will have to attach an event listener to your checkbox, and toggle the button visibility on `change`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you. Also as well have a lot of the same questions answered.

```
$("#id_10139347").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kevin I prepared a simple solution with only CSS to show button when you click on the Checkbox. I Hope this can help you

```
  <label for="id_10139347"> CHECK BOX </label>
   <input class="suscriptionCheck" id="id_10139347" type="checkbox" name="id_10139347">
   <br/>
 <button>SOME BUTTON</button>

button {
  display: none;
}
.suscriptionCheck:checked ~ button{
  display:block;
  padding: 14px;
  
}
```

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/poygbXr

Comment: Hi Matias, I believe this solution only works if theyre  in the same DIV. Do you have a solution if the button is in a separate DIV?

Comment: Yes, I make this always with Javascript or Jquery, do you have Jquery in your project ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/poygbXr?editors=1111  this is the code updated for javascript use

Comment: I feel like we're close! I do have JQuery in the project but I don't have access to the HTML on the input checkbox, but I have it's ID. Is it possible to run this without the onClick action in the HTML?

Comment: Yes with. set attribute in Javascript. https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/poygbXr?editors=1111  Update code

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
function displayButton(item) {
  if (item.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="id_10139347" type="checkbox" name="id_10139347" onclick="displayButton(this)">

<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

This triggers the `displayButton()` function when the input box is clicked. If the input is checked, the button is displayed. Else, it's not displayed.